# ESP32 driving Solenoid requiring 2A/24V DC with IRF520?

Tags: esp32, solenoid-valve

I am trying to design a circuit, which will drive my home valves which is on 24V and by specifications must supply 2A ( but this is quite suspicious, and probably it is requiring much lower current, but sill I wish to make it fulfill this requirement ).
I found a few circuits, but when I doublechecked them - most of them ends with an issue.
So, just as a precaution I wish to ask peoples which done this eventually for guide.

- How to drive IRF520 with ESP32 3.3V output correctly ?

Comment: Is the application using the IRF520 FET as a simple on/off switch, or do you need to PWM control it? And if you need PWM at what frequency? If it's just an on/off you could use a smaller logic level controllable FET to control the gate voltage of the IRF520. Perhaps with a resistor divider on your 24V rail to maintain Vgs < 20V.

Comment: Nope, no PWM. Just simple switching on/off the solenoid.

Comment: I've moved the topic here, after the practitioners in the discussion pointed me more toward the right question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/563848/simple-esp32-driver-for-solenoid-valve-rated-24v-2a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience with 24V solenoid valves, they don't need the maximum listed current. For a 2A solenoid it probably needs 1-1.5A to activate, and then ~500mA to hold open. You can design circuits which supply this.

The listed mosfet has a threshold voltage between 2 and 4 volts, so it's likely the ESP32 can't turn it on from 3.3V. You would want a smaller mosfet to drive the gate on it.

This is a really obnoxious part to design this circuit with, because the gate voltage range is above a microcontroller but it's also below 24v. I would encourage you to get a logic level mosfet if you have the option to. That way you don't need to worry about all of these gate voltage thresholds, and you could use 1 mosfet and 1 resistor.

This is the best I could come up with, it should be compatible with most garden variety p-mosfets and n-mosfets, and a handful of 10k resistors:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNvl6U.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

EDIT:

This is how it would simplify with a logic-level mosfet.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqY55N.png)</sup>

Very easy to find a new part with:

- VDS of greater than 24V, 30 is very common
- Current rating greater than 2A
- low RDSon specified between 1.8-4.5V, usually means its logic level
- VGSth max of 3.3V or less
- low input capacitance, otherwise put a series resistor

Comment: Nice and welcome

Comment: If OP is able to adjust the program on the microcontroller, couldn't they invert the output (pull output pin low to energize solenoid) and omit M5, R6 & R7?

Comment: @Theodore I don't believe so, the pin would need to be tolerant of 24v if it's in open drain due to R5. If that was the case you could high-side switch the solenoid with M4 & R5 directly and omit everything else

Comment: I am absolutely thanksful for this circuit and the time you've spend to help me guys.
This going to quite complicate the things probably, but if there is no other way I will go this one.
Is there is some other simpler solution - with other transistor or something else, requiring less components.
Actually it's IRF520 what's google throw at me. If there is other, simpler way. Please.

Comment: I will edit the answer to show how it simplifies if you choose a different mosfet

Comment: @zozwold ...of course you're right... it would have to be M1 that's omitted and M4 would have to be a power PMOS high-side.

Comment: Maybe it is the best to accept this answer, and post another question. So more peoples will benefit from both ?

Comment: I've moved the topic here : https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/563848/simple-esp32-driver-for-solenoid-valve-rated-24v-2a

Comment: what common cheap transistor would fit this new circuit then ?

Comment: I don't think part recommendations are allowed here, you would need to do a parametric search on an electronics supplier site using similar specs to the edit. I did a quick one and found some in the IRLxxx and IRLZxx series. IRLZ24 / IRLZ14 both have good specs, but I know the IRLZ44N can be found everywhere. Those would be good places to start.

Comment: Just wish to confirm if I am on a right track with IRL3705N which is available in the local store.
https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irl3705n.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153565f29f42532

Comment: That looks like a good choice to me, the important specs (gate threshold, on resistance, VDS) all fit very well. It has fairly high input capacitance but that shouldn't be much of an issue if it's just being used as an on/off switch. Best practice dictates a series resistor from the mcu pin to the gate to prevent too much initial current draw, but I almost never do this on small mosfets.